# how to use applozic in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, applozic

I want to use Applozic chat application in my Web application being built in MVC5. But I need guide to use this service in my application.

Any step by step process will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its a web application so javascript plugin should work:
https://docs.applozic.com/docs/web-javascript-chat-plugin